# SQL Server : get next date of last minimum negative amount date with group by sum

Tags: sql-server-2008

I  have a table like this:

```
date        amt    sr
----------------------
2013-07-01  -10     1
2013-07-02   40     2
2013-07-03   10     3
2013-07-04  -10     4
2013-07-06   10     5
2013-07-07  -10     6
2013-07-08   10     7
2013-07-09   10     8
2013-07-10   10     9
```

I want this result:

```
date            amt    sr
--------------------------
2013-07-08       60     7
```

Get next date of last minimum negative amount date

Comment: Can you clarify what your algorithm is? It's unclear how you get the result amt of 60.

Comment: 60 is a sum of amt value group by date. there is no need of sr no.

Comment: So the sum doesn't care what the date you find is, it's just a sum of all the values? Are the dates always contiguous?

Comment: where is a group by?  If you grouped the above provided results on date amt would be 10, not 60

Comment: "last minimum negative amount date" last in relation to what ordering?  date? tr? there is no "order of rows" in a database until one is specified, right now we have to make a lot of assumptions about your question.  Please clarify.

Comment: date will not be in continuous order. date is always in asc. order

Comment: I don't want result group by date. i want only sum of amount group by next column that is emp value is 'E001'. Against of emp we want some of amount and date which is just next date of max date of negative amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a table called `date_value` with a `date` and `int` columns called `dat` and `value`

Then you can get the desired result by:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT MIN(dat) FROM dbo.date_value 
    WHERE dat > ( SELECT MAX(dat) FROM dbo.date_value WHERE val < 0 )
) AS 'date', 
SUM(val) AS 'amt'
FROM dbo.date_value
```